# how to get a random array from a array?

Tags: java

```
String[] s={"a","b","c","d"};//['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['a','b'],['a ','c'],['a','d'],['b','c'],['b','d'],['c','d'],['a ','b','c']...['a','b','c','d']
```

I want a result like this. Relying on this array, I want to get a random value among them.

Comment: What about an empty array?

Comment: Empty arrays also count

Comment: What have you tried yet? Share some code perhaps!

Comment: Can the randomized array contain duplicate elements, can it's size be bigger than the source:
Ex: [a,b] -> [a,a,b,b] is it okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just randomly choose if a String is used in the result or not for every String in the array:

```java
String[] s={"a","b","c","d"};
Random rand=new Random();
List<String> sList=new ArrayList<>();
for(String elem:s){
    if(rand.nextBoolean()){
        sList.add(elem);
    }
}
String[] result=sList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Or using streams:

```java
String[] s={"a","b","c","d"};
Random rand=new Random();
String[] result=Arrays.stream(s).filter(unused->rand.nextBoolean()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: `sList.toArray(s)` -> `sList.toArray(String[]::new)` `.filter(rand::nextBoolean)` -> `.filter(x -> rand.nextBoolean())`

Comment: [`List#toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) expects an array as a parameter, not an array constructor (you might have confused it with `Stream#toArray`). However, thanks for your other improvement.

Comment: @dan1st, `sList.toArray(s)` may produce results with `null`: `[b, null, c, d]` or even `[c, null, c, d]`; both `sList.toArray(new String[0])` and `sList.toArray(String[]::new)` work fine.  The latter works because of the default implementation [`Collection::toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction))

Comment: My fault. I thought it would always create a new array.